# Zapier returns object arrays with empty fields - need to add empty strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, zapier

I could use some help adding empty strings in an array returned by Zapier for emails that has blanks indicated by commas. It looks like this:

input email `jbrooks_ca@yahoo.com,,,,jkburtie@gmail.com,skyelea@hotmail.com,`etc...

What I'd like it to look like is:
`jbrooks_ca@yahoo.com,'','','',jkburtie@gmail.com,skyelea@hotmail.com,`

If anyone is familiar with writing JS for Zapier I would love some insight as I'm not very strong at writing JS.

Here are the two screens in Zapier handling the code output as reference.

[the initial content pulled by Zapier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2e5Px.png)

[the output content once the JS has rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VY0MJ.png)

Answer (score 2):

Try this in the Zapier Code box:

```
var emails = input.email.split(',');
var new_emails_str = "";
for (var i in emails) {
    var e = emails[i];
    if (e) {
        new_emails_str += e + ",";
    } else {
        new_emails_str += "'',"; 
    }
}
output = [{emails: new_emails_str}];
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Result I see when testing:

[image]